# Named (map) constructors do not work in grails.gsp.PageRenderer

Tags: grails

When I use a map constructor like:

```
Person p = new Person(name: "Bob")
```

through something that is called via a grails.gsp.PageRenderer, the field values are not populated.  When I use an empty constructor and then set the fields individually like:

```
Person p = new Person()
p.name = "Bob"
```

it succeeds.  When I use the map constructor via a `render` call, it also succeeds.

Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Sample project is here in case anyone wants to dig deeper: https://github.com/danduke/constructor-test/

Actual use case, as requested by Jeff below:

- I have a computationally expensive view to render.  Essentially it's a multi-thousand page (when PDF'd) view of some data.
- This view can be broken into smaller pieces, and I can reliably determine when each has changed.
- I render one piece at a time, submitting each piece to a fixed size thread pool to avoid overloading the system.  I left this out of the example project, as it has no bearing on the results.
- I cache the rendered results and evict them by key when data in that portion of the view has changed.  **This is why I am using a page renderer.**
- Each template used may make use of various tag libraries.
- Some tag libraries need to load data from other applications in order to display things properly (actual use case: loading preferences from a shared repository for whether particular items are enabled in the view)
- When loaded, these items need to be turned into an object.  In my case, it's a GORM object.  **This is why I am creating a new object at all.**

There are quite a few opportunities for improvement in my actual use case, and I'm open to suggestions on that.  However, the simplest possible (for me) demonstration of the problem still does suggest that there's a problem.  I'm curious whether it **should** be possible to use map constructors in something called from a PageRenderer at all.  I'm surprised that it doesn't work, and it feels like a bug, but obviously a very precise and edge case one.

Comment: The example project is obviously an oversimplified case; in my real project the gsp calls a taglib which calls a service, and the page renderer is used via  thread pool to control performance and caching.  The example project is as simple as I could make it and still demonstrate the error.

Comment: The code at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/48dc7378badf50faa8572125838a47df596c64f2/grails-plugin-mimetypes/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/mime/HttpServletRequestExtension.groovy#L74 is throwing an exception because the `ServletContext` can't be retrieved.  The code in the project is doing unusual things.  I know you did that to boil it down to a simple scenario but I can't tell what actual use case would lead to this.  Can you help clarify that?

Comment: I don't see any exceptions when I run it; is that swallowed somewhere?  But to answer your question: I'm going to update it into the question because I don't think it's going to fit well into a comment.

Comment: I do suspect that this is a situation of "doing unusual things and uncovered a bug, but one that maybe two people in the world would ever care about".  I'm fine if that's the case...just trying to determine if it's something that's (1) actually a bug and (2) even worth reporting.

Comment: " I'm fine if that's the case...just trying to determine if it's something that's (1) actually a bug and (2) even worth reporting." - I think technically it is a bug. Feel free to report it.  It would be good to know if there is a way to recreate the problem when following more typical practices.  Doing https://github.com/danduke/constructor-test/blob/9d680eb23f00e6e054ad94336fe950fa9ad28a9d/grails-app/views/test.gsp in a GSP isn't a typical thing and there isn't a good reason to do that, but it may be that the issue can be triggered in other ways.

Comment: I can definitely add a taglib to the example project if you'll feel better about gsp->taglib->service.  That's far more normal...just wasn't necessary for the minimal reproducible case so I left it out.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Indeed that is a better way to represent the problem as it rules out some things.  Thanks!

Comment: Example project updated with taglib, and bug reported https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11870  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"Technically it is a bug" (which is the best kind of bug!), and has been reported here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11870

I'll update this if/when additional information is available.